# How to remove this error in OneHotEncoder function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

**Code->**

```
# Data Preprocessing
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, :3].values

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.str)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
Y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y)
```

**Error->**

```
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
C:\Users\DELL PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:415: FutureWarning: The handling of integer data will change in version 0.22. Currently, the categories are determined based on the range [0, max(values)], while in the future they will be determined based on the unique values.
If you want the future behaviour and silence this warning, you can specify "categories='auto'".
In case you used a LabelEncoder before this OneHotEncoder to convert the categories to integers, then you can now use the OneHotEncoder directly.
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
Y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-35a352cd76da>", line 2, in <module>
    Y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y)

  File "C:\Users\DELL PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 235, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

  File "C:\Users\DELL PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 760, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (10, 3)
```

**Data.csv**
[Data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0bDJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

`Y = dataset.iloc[:, :3].values`

actually gives you all columns 0:2. I'm assuming what you really wanted was:

`Y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values`